# How can I set the overridedefaultbutton to tab in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can I set the **overridedefaultbutton** to **Tab** so that pressing **Enter** tabs to the next input field, and doesn't cause a postback?

Comment: sounds like your users want a website to act like the old mainframe screens - i kinda feel sorry for you - here is another question that might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3286174/capturing-onkeydown-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this jQuery:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13){
      $(":input:eq(" + $(":input").index(this) + 1 + ")");
      return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

It should add the `onkeydown` method to all elements of type input.  Then if the `e.keyCode` is the enter key (13) then it will focus on the next element of type input.

sourced from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923683/prevent-users-from-submitting-form-by-hitting-enter-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290535/best-way-to-find-next-form-input-element-in-jquery)